# React + Redux + REST

Tags: mongodb, rest, reactjs, meteor, redux

Presento mi duda:

- Tengo que hacer una API REST para clientes externos.
- Necesito tener 3 aplicaciones diferentes, 1 de uso interno, 1 de uso externo y la API, que se conectarán (a parte de los clientes externos) las otras 2 aplicaciones.

Estamos utilizando para la API REST Meteor.js, para el frontend React y MongoDB para la base de datos. ¿Es una buena práctica utilizar Redux en este caso? La información "debe" ser reactiva y que cuando un cliente modifique algo, otro distinto pueda ver la modificación. Si esto no es posible, ¿qué opciones tengo o qué patrones / librerías debería utilizar?

Comment: Pienso que la pregunta es muy de alto nivel (poco concreta para lo que se suele pedir en SO) y, por tanto, muy dada a que cualquier respuesta se base en opiniones más que en hechos objetivos. Cualquier pregunta del tipo "¿debería usar la librería/framework X?" puede dar pie a interminables discusiones

Comment: De ahí que pregunte, para ver las opiniones de la gente y en base a todas las respuestas, tomar la decisión que más se adecue a mis necesidades ^^. Si no crees que es el sitio adecuado, ¿qué sitio puedes recomendarme?

Comment: Concuerto con Pablo de que esta pregunta es más de opinión personal sobre arquitecturas, pero te recomiendo que no implementes Redux en tu aplicación de React hasta que sea necesario, los mismos desarrolladores de Redux pusieron un post en su documentación explicando este punto te dejo el [link en inglés](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367). Sobre la API existen varios frameworks que te pueden hacer la vida mas fácil, en lo personal uso [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) para construir mis APIs.

Comment: La API en si no es un problema, es más, ya está funcional. El problema viene a ser cómo tratar la API con React, ya que actualmente estoy tratandolo en base a estados y no se si es correcto hacerlo de esa forma ya que el proyecto es ENORME.